# Meaning of "level a gap in the middle for the trains connection point to make contact"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of level in *level a gap*, and *connection point*?

> Why can't they put a protective sleeve of the power rail, that the train can still access through. But make it hard for a person to accidentally fall on. For such a sue friend society, I find it strange many people have sued the transit system for accidental deaths
>
> Because insulating a conductor so it doesn't conduct defeats the entire purpose of having a conductor in the first place.
>
> You can have two support structures on either side that are higher than the rail and still **level a gap** in the middle for the trains **connection point** to make contact. Then if you fail on it, you shouldn't make accidental contact.

Comment: Where did you get the original text from?

Comment: It's from a thread on a forum I visit.

Comment: Given the other problems in the selection (eg *sue friend* rather than *sue-friendly*, missing question mark, missing period, non sequitur in third sentence, missing apostrophe in *trains*, and *if you fail on it* instead of *if you fall on it*) it is no stretch at all to see that *level* is a typo for *leave*.  The question is too localized and should be closed and deleted.

Comment: I think it's obvious *level* should be *leave* (as *fail* should be *fall*), but quite frankly, this entire text seems to have been written by an illiterate. It's way Too Localised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that *level* is a mistake for *leave*.

I think it was intended to read

> and still leave a gap in the middle for the train's connection point to make contact.

Answer (score 1):

As Colin mentioned in his answer, and I in my comment, *level* evidently is a mistake or typo and should be *leave*.

Regarding the term *connection point*: This refers to the point of contact between the train's shoe and the current-carrying high-voltage third rail used in some electrified train systems.
[image]

A more-detailed picture of a shoe appears at [railway-technical.com](http://www.railway-technical.com/etracp.shtml), where the above image is from.